# RSpec controller for nested resources, before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

Let say I have setup like this:

config/routes.rb

```
  resources :graves do
    resources :candles
  end
```

app/models/grave.rb

```
has_many :candles, dependent: :destroy
```

app/models/candles.rb

```
belongs_to :grave
```

app/controllers/candles_controller.rb

```
before_action :get_grave

def create
  @candle = @grave.candles.new(candle_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @candle.save
        format.html {
          redirect_to @grave, notice: 'Candle was successfully created.'
        }
        format.json { }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @candle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

private
def candle_params
  params.require(:candle).permit(:name, :body)
end

def get_grave
  @grave = Grave.find(params[:grave_id])
end
```

spec/controllers/candles_controller_spec.rb

```
describe CandlesController, type: :controller do
  describe "POST create" do
    before(:each) do
      @grave = FactoryGirl.create(:grave)
    end
    it "creates candle" do
      post :create, candle: { name: "Dummy name", body: "Dummy body", grave_id: @grave.id}
      expect(response).to redirect_to(@grave)
    end
  end
end
```

Problem is when I run this spec I get this error:

> 1) CandlesController POST create creates candle
>        Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(@grave)
>          Expected response to be a < redirect >, but was <404>

I've checked FactoryGirl and `@grave` is created so it's not nil. When I test manually `candle` is created correctly and it's associated to `grave`. Any clues what may cause spec to fail?

Rails 4.2, RSpec 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route will look like this: `graves/:grave_id/candles`, so you have to pass a `@grave.id` to your `post` method as `grave_id`.

```
post :create, grave_id: @grave.id, candle: { name: "Dummy name", body: "Dummy body", grave_id: @grave.id}
```